# Why are my line chart intervals wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, linechart

I have a google line chart created to display values based on time intervals. Here is my complete graph setup:

```
 var inputData = [[1990,5335293,"Jan 1990\n5,335,293"],[1990,5309932,"Feb 1990\n5,309,932"],[1990,5327306,"Mar 1990\n5,327,306"],[1990,5354168,"Apr 1990\n5,354,168"],[1990,5394006,"May 1990\n5,394,006"],[1990,5448990,"Jun 1990\n5,448,990"],[1990,5474112,"Jul 1990\n5,474,112"],[1990,5446876,"Aug 1990\n5,446,876"],[1990,5382558,"Sep 1990\n5,382,558"],[1990,5410053,"Oct 1990\n5,410,053"],[1990,5399647,"Nov 1990\n5,399,647"],[1990,5386422,"Dec 1990\n5,386,422"]] ;
        var month = "All Months" ;

        if (month == "All Months") {
        var b = [];
        for (i=0; i < inputData.length; i++) {

            var year_with_month = inputData[i][0] + i * 1/12;
            var e = [year_with_month, inputData[i][1], inputData [i][2]]
            b.push(e);

        }
        inputData = b;
        }

 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {    
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', month);
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addRows(inputData);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({groupingSymbol: ',', fractionDigits: '0'});
    formatter.format(data, 1);  

    var options = {
    tooltip: {textStyle: {bold: 'false', color: 'black'}},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '####', viewWindowMode:'maximized'},
   vAxis: {title: 'Number in Labor Force'},
   colors:['green'],


    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I use an if statement to change each 1st element in an array to add 1/12 based on whatever month it is. The line and the graph itself look great. However, my haxis intervals are not even close to being right. When I look at my graph, three of the h axis intervals are 1991. The line goes through each of these intervals, but as you can see, none of the data values ever become 1991. I guess what I am saying is, how do I alter these haxis values so they line up with my data points instead of being incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a "date" type axis instead of a "number" type, and input your data as Date objects, like this:

```
var inputData = [[1990,5335293,"Jan 1990\n5,335,293"],[1990,5309932,"Feb 1990\n5,309,932"],[1990,5327306,"Mar 1990\n5,327,306"],[1990,5354168,"Apr 1990\n5,354,168"],[1990,5394006,"May 1990\n5,394,006"],[1990,5448990,"Jun 1990\n5,448,990"],[1990,5474112,"Jul 1990\n5,474,112"],[1990,5446876,"Aug 1990\n5,446,876"],[1990,5382558,"Sep 1990\n5,382,558"],[1990,5410053,"Oct 1990\n5,410,053"],[1990,5399647,"Nov 1990\n5,399,647"],[1990,5386422,"Dec 1990\n5,386,422"]] ;
var month = "All Months" ;

if (month == "All Months") {
    var b = [];
    for (i=0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
        var d = new Date(inputData[i][0], i, 1);
        var e = [d, inputData[i][1], inputData [i][2]];
        b.push(e);
    }
    inputData = b;
}
function drawChart() {    
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', month);
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    data.addRows(inputData);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({groupingSymbol: ',', fractionDigits: 0});
    formatter.format(data, 1);  

    var options = {
        tooltip: {textStyle: {bold: 'false', color: 'black'}},
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: 'MMM yyyy', viewWindowMode:'maximized'},
        vAxis: {title: 'Number in Labor Force'},
        colors:['green']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

This would also allow you to skip your custom tooltips, as the dates can be formatted the way you want them:

```
var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMM yyyy'});
dateFormatter.format(data, 0);
```

See working example based on your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/XdncE/

Comment: This works great if you are just basing it on one year, but it doesn't work if you have say 4 years inside the inputData array.

Comment: var inputData = [[1990,5335293],[1990,5309932],[1990,5327306],[1990,5354168],[1990,5394006],[1990,5448990],[1990,5474112],[1990,5446876],[1990,5382558],[1990,5410053],[1990,5399647],[1990,5386422],[1991,5329520],[1991,5353131],[1991,5382615],[1991,5384256],[1991,5379892],[1991,5473590],[1991,5498405],[1991,5443969],[1991,5385556],[1991,5404738],[1991,5394658],[1991,5384613],[1992,5370549],[1992,5385960],[1992,5415314],[1992,5424056],[1992,5474452],[1992,5570736],[1992,5608156],[1992,5566925],[1992,5479084],[1992,5473027],[1992,5474260],[1992,5459028]] ;

Comment: Really, the best solution is to include "month" in your data, so you know for certain which data point goes with which month.  Implicitly assigning months like this can get you into trouble.  Is your data guaranteed to include 12 months of data for every year?